# font import not working in any browser after uploading the files to the server

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

Here's the link to what I'm dealing with: http://henrygillis.com/henryslife/

If I live-preview my files from Brackets the proper fonts show up. But after uploading it to my server it does not work (if you check the link above). Is this a problem with font-face? Am I missing something in the code? This has been driving me crazy.
Everything else works as intended except for the fonts. I'm thankful for any help!

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'brandontext-black';
    src: local('BrandonText-Black.otf'), url('../fonts/BrandonText-Black.otf') format('opentype');
    src: local('BrandonText-Black.woff'), url('../fonts/BrandonText-Black.woff') format('woff');
    src: local('BrandonText-Black.ttf'), url('../fonts/BrandonText-Black.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'brandontext-light';
    src: local('BrandonText-Light.otf'), url('../fonts/BrandonText-Light.otf') format('opentype');
     src: local('BrandonText-Light.woff'), url('../fonts/BrandonText-Light.woff') format('woff');
     src: local('BrandonText-Light.ttf'), url('../fonts/BrandonText-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'brandontext-regular';
    src: local('BrandonText-Regular.otf'), url('../fonts/BrandonText-Regular.otf') format('opentype');
    src: local('BrandonText-Regular.woff'), url('../fonts/BrandonText-Regular.woff') format('woff');
    src: local('BrandonText-Regular.ttf'), url('../fonts/BrandonText-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal;
}
body {
    font-family: 'BrandonText-Black', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

Some HTML:

```
 <article class="entry" id="entry_19-06-2014">
            <div class="background" style="background-image: url('Images/19-06-2014.jpg')"></div>
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Stealing couches like hob(r)os</h1>
                <h2>then putting them back like good citicens</h2>
                <h3><em>19th</em> of June, 2014 - <em>Meat Packers District</em>, Chicago</h3>
                <div class="seperator">
                    <img src="Design/Seperator_02.svg">
                </div>
                <p>Random projections have recently emerged as a powerful method for dimensionality reduction. Theoretical results indicate not much.</p>
            </div>
        </article>
```

**EDIT:**
I changed all the paths to absolute paths as per your suggestion. 
The fonts are still not loading though. It's just a different error: The GET requests on the font-files simply get canceled.

Comment: The URLs are not correct. This is something you have to solve locally or ask for help from someone who has access to the server you are using. Currently it seems that the GET requests get redirected to an address that results in 404 Not Found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually when this happens it's either the fonts are not correctly uploaded into the server or the relative path is not valid anymore on the server, try to put an absolute path like:
`src: local('BrandonText-Black.otf'), url('http://www.example.com/fonts/BrandonText-Black.otf') format('opentype');`

**EDIT**
You can look in the "Network" tab of your browser's inspector if there is a 404 error when loading you fonts files.

Comment: I will second this. The font files are in the incorrect location or the path pointing to the font files is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! And for the tip with the Network tab, didn't know about that. 

I changed all the paths to absolute paths. Now there is a canceled message when trying to load the fonts. Any ideas?

Comment: Hm I tried to call this link : "http://www.henrygillis.com/fonts/BrandonText-Regular.ttf" and it return a 404 on your website instead of a download prompt for the font. So it seems like the link is "valid" as it doesn't return a 404 from apache but from you website / framework. Do you have some sort of url rewriting ? The path of your fonts could be good but might be overrided by your rewrites directives.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't correctly linking the font files inside your CSS. These are the errors appearing when I check the console of your website:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://henrygillis.com/fonts/BrandonText-Black.ttf
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://henrygillis.com/fonts/BrandonText-Light.ttf
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://henrygillis.com/fonts/BrandonText-Regular.ttf
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this was the initial problem. But it just cancels the GET requests on the fonts now. Any ideas?

Comment: @mcgoldfish the font source still seems to be incorrect. For example, if you try opening `http://henrygillis.com/fonts/BrandonText-Light.ttf` in your browser, it returns a `404: Not Found` error.